# Laravel and Json : return the name of the array

Tags: json, laravel

I'm trying to return a JSON of data stored in my database, it works but it does not show the name of the array.

I'm using Laravel.

My code :

```
<?php

class PlayerController extends BaseController {

public function checkupdate()
{
    $datapack = DB::table('datapack')->get();


    if (Request::isJson()) {
        return Response::json($datapack,200);
    }

    return Response::json($datapack,200,[],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    //return View::make('view');
}

}
```

which give me :

```
[
    {
        "id": "FD314",
        "timeUpdated": 1401184091        
    }
]
```

and I want something like this :

```
[
    "datapack" : {
        "id": "FD314",
        "timeUpdated": 1401184091        
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it under a `datapack` key

```
return Response::json(['datapack'=>$datapack],200);
```